# How to create custom text box attribute for configurable product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create configurable product with dropdown and textbox field attributes. In frontend product detail page, dropdown can be shown but I also want to show textbox. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Is that your custom field to enter value from frontend?

Comment: yes, I want to enter value in frontend

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module create an xml file like this,

```
app/code/Module/Namespace/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

In that xml file, paste the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Module_Namespace::product/view/options/type/select.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create a template file in this path

```
app/code/Module/Namespace/view/frontend/template/product/view/options/type/select.phtml
```

Then you can add your custom input text field code in that file.

Eg: First name: `<input type="text" name="firstname">`

Comment: Dropdown I can make by using configurable product but problem is with input text field. I want to do using configurable product

Comment: you can also add text field here.. eg:  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">